# I am getting syntax errors and don't know how to fix them

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near ','

and do not know how to fix it.

I have tried rewriting the query, referencing old code, and nothing seems to work.

```
USE RewriteExam
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects
          WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Vendors')
            AND type IN ('U'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Vendors table already exists, dropping it now!'
    DROP TABLE Vendors
END
GO

PRINT 'Creating the "Vendors" Table'

CREATE TABLE dbo.Vendors 
(
    VendorID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    VendorName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    VendorAddress VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    VendorCity VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    VendorState VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    VendorZipCode VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    VendorPhone VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    VendorContactLName VARCHAR(7) NULL,
    VendorContactFName VARCHAR(14) NULL,
    AcountNo INT NOT NULL,
    ModifiedDate SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    AccountNo INT FOREIGN KEY,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Vendors_VendorID 
         PRIMARY KEY (VendorID)
    --REFERENCES Vendors (VendorID)
);
GO

PRINT 'Creating the "GLAccounts" Table'

CREATE TABLE dbo.GLAccounts 
(
    AccountNo INT PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountDescription VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);
GO
```

The trouble is in the constraints. The comma after the foreign key is giving me the error as well as `PRIMARY KEY (VendorID)`

Comment: Hint:  `REFERENCES`.

Comment: The CREATE TABLE docs show how to correctly create Foreign and Primary keys.   I have no idea where you got the idea of doing it the way you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add the commented out part after

`AccountNo INT FOREIGN KEY`

and convert to

`AccountNo INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Vendors (VendorID)`

and remove already defined constraint `PRIMARY KEY (VendorID)`